# bootstrap vs bootstrapModule

Tags: angular

[This article](https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/angular-2-an-introduction-of-bootstrap-and-providers-1c60ffbb7604#.8xw5nbj73) describes the `bootstrap` function used to bootstrap angular app:

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent)
    .then(success => console.log('Bootstrap successfully!'))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

However, I'm bootstrapping the app like this:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';    
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

What's the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since **2.0.0-rc.5 (2016-08-09)** there is no longer the `bootstrap` function.

You need to use `platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule` instead.

More about it you can read at changelog page

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-rc5-2016-08-09

Comment: thanks, bootstrap took `HTTP_PROVIDERS` in the article like this `bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS, CarService])`. Is my understanding correct that I should put those into `providers` in the app module that is used for bootstrapping?

Comment: Use it like this `imports: [HttpModule], providers: [CarService]` in your `@NgModule`

Comment: thanks, just to clarify, [the example here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/XHRBackend-class.html) is also obsolete? there's no need to inject `HTTP_PROVIDERS` since they are provided globally by `http` module, correct?